# Send push notification to specific user ID when properties for user changed

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I am wondering how I can automatically trigger sending a push notification from [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) to a specific user ID (`PFUser`) when the properties of that user has changed. For example, say the user verifies his/her user account related email, how can I send a notification once that happens to let the user know that the email was successfully verified?

I would read the push notification using method:

```
(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

But, suggestions as for how to trigger sending the notification would appreciated.

Comment: I think for email verification you should send passcode(4 digit number) to users email id, ask him to enter that passcode in your a check through the webservice check if he enter correct one or not

Answer (score 0):

Generally, beforeSave and afterSave Cloud Code hooks (see: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers) are great for running code based on updates to an object.

However, it appears as if these hooks may not work for the emailVerified fields (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/m4Jba0ZhMhY). A quick solution would be to create a background job that checks for users who have emailVerified and use a BOOL variable to track whether you've run your post-verification job on that user -- maybe not ideal due to the extra bool and job, but should cover your case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use device token to achieve the functionality, device token is the unique idea of device and doesn't vary on user property, push notification can be sent to device directly not to user. Push can be implemented by this without any issue.